# Возникает ошибка "необработанное исключение типа System.StackOverflowException"

Tags: c#

Привет.
Возникает ошибка "необработанное исключение типа System.StackOverflowException"

На этой строке:         Form1 Control = new Form1();

Я обращаюсь к контролам в своём классе из Form1.Designer.cs

Код

```
namespace PC_Atmega161
{
class Common
{

    Form1 Control = new Form1();
    UART UART_copy = new UART();

    public void init()
    {
        // Настройка кнопки отправки запроса
        //buttonSend.Width = dataGridView1.Width;

        // Настройка ComboBox
        string[] ComPortNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        for (int i = 0; i < ComPortNames.Length; i++)
        {
            Control.comboBox1.Items.Add(ComPortNames[i]);
        }
    }

    public void ShowInMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RowCount" + Control.dataGridView2.RowCount);
        for (int i = Control.dataGridView2.RowCount; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("i: " + i);
            if (i == 1)
            {
                break;
            }
            Control.dataGridView2.Rows[i - 1].Cells[0].Value = Control.dataGridView2.Rows[i - 2].Cells[0].Value;
        }

        Control.dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = UART_copy.InMessage[0].ToString("x");
        Control.dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = UART_copy.InMessage[1].ToString("x");
        Control.dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = UART_copy.InMessage[2].ToString("x");
        Control.dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = UART_copy.InMessage[3].ToString("x");
        Control.dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value = UART_copy.InMessage[4].ToString("x");
        Control.dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value = "0" + UART_copy.InMessage[5].ToString("x");
        Control.dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[6].Value = "0" + UART_copy.InMessage[6].ToString("x");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Лучше всего запустить в дебаге. Тогда при "выкидыше" исключения в окошке CallStack будет видно, какой именно метод "хулиганит".

Comment: Ну так если выкидывает при создании экземпляра Form1, то и ищите проблему в конструкторе класса Form1, а не в этом коде который вы выложили!